# C++: sscanf behavior

Tags: c++, pointers, scanf

Can someone help me understand this piece of code:

```
    char *line = new char[2048];
    char *probableCauseStr = new char[512];
    char *additioanl_text = new char[512];
    long holdPeriod = 0;

    while( !f.eof() ) {
            f.getline( line, 2048 );
            //
            // find the ',' seperator
            //
            char* p = StrMgt::strchr( line, ',' );
            if( !p ) continue;
            *p = '\0';
            p++;
            if( sscanf( line, "%s%s", probableCauseStr, additioanl_text ) != 1 || 
                sscanf( p, "%ld%s", &holdPeriod, additioanl_text ) != 1 ) continue;

            ....
```

I'm lost trying to figure out what happens with the character pointer p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p` is used to find the first comma and replace it with `\0` (which is the end-of-string for C-style strings, in particular for sscanf). Then `p` is incremented to point at the next character.

So a string like

```
"Hello world, 100000"
```

becomes

```
line -> "Hello world"
p -> " 100000"
```

Then the two sscanfs are tried, checking for whichever one returns 1 (which means that it parsed exactly 1 value). In this example, the first sscanf would return 2 (since there are two words), so the second one will be called, and will return 1, with `holdPeriod` getting the value `100000`.

Comment: Thanks.  This explains the behavior expected.

Answer (score 2):

The char pointer `p` incremented to next char, then it the second `sscanf` reads data from a memory location the incremented pointer points to.

From the code, I can say the reason why `p` is incremented because initially the first char of `p` is assigned with `\0`. So it's incremented to the next char, to make it point to an integral value, so that `sscanf` can read it with `%ld` specifier. After this, `sscanf` reads a string with `%s` specifier.

Comment: The person who wrote that code needs some lessons on adding comments to his code and about magic numbers. (p.s: Saw on the homepage today that Nawaz got a gold medal today. Congrats Nawaz! :) )

Comment: @Nav: thanks. BTW, how did you come to know that I got gold medal TODAY?

Comment: The homepage shows a list of the most recently earned badges. Maybe not 'today', but 'recently'.